# Select2 Bottom of placeholder text is getting cut off

Tags: html, css, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

[image]

The bottom of the placeholder text on this Select2 multiple select is getting cut-off, how can I edit the CSS classes of this input to stop this from happening.

Here is my current code:

```
<style>
    .select2-container {
      width: 100% !important;
    }
</style>

<label for="last-name" class="block text-sm font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900">Language(s)</label>
<div class="mt-2 w-full">
  <select class="select-language w-full rounded-md" name="languages" multiple="multiple">
    {% for language in languages %}
      <option value="{{ language }}">{{ language }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
</div>

  <script>
$('.select-language').select2({
        placeholder: 'Select languages',
        allowClear: true,
        multiple: true
});
</script>
```

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Can you add a working code link with a stack overflow account so that it will be easy to understand the code because if I run this it will give me such output https://onecompiler.com/html/3za3ry5an